# Print the number of elements in an ICollection in an exception message

Tags: c#, exception, icollection

I have a collection of items and I want to throw an exception to the user, how many items there are in the collection - if it contains more or less than 1.

This might seem quite simple, but I don't know how to print the number of elements it contains.

my collection variable is called myCollection and it contains 3 elements.

I've tried something like this:

```
if(myCollection?.count != 1){
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("myCollection contains {0} elements", myCollection?.count}
}
```

But it tells me, the following:

> "Cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Exception"

Can anyone help, please.

Comment: please refer following link -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_ArgumentOutOfRangeException__ctor_System_String_

Comment: You should do `new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"myCollection contains {myCollection?.count}");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to format the exception message as in OP, you could use either of the following approaches

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("myCollection contains {0} elements", myCollection?.count));
```

or

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"myCollection contains {myCollection?.count} elements);
```